# Filtering in Listactivity through adapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, listactivity

> I m trying filter my route points in a listview which are populated to layout. In ***Initialize View portion***,  I debug the code and its working fine, as its looking up for route name which matches the search bar entered value and its passing it to adapter.getFilter().filter(s);. However maybe the filter is not working properly or layout is not refreshed due to which my customized adapter values are not displaying on the layout after search.

**Activity Class**

```
public class SelectRoutePointsActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener{
SelectRoutePointsActivity.MyAdapter adapter;
SelectRoutePointsActivity.MyAdapter lva;
long routePointID = -1;
Context this_;
private EditText inputSearch;
public SelectRoutePointsActivity(){
    this_ = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.route_layout);
    init();
}
```

**initialize view**

```
void init(){
    RouteDB db = new RouteDB(this_);
    db.open();
    Cursor cur = db.getAll();

    adapter = new SelectRoutePointsActivity.MyAdapter(this_, cur, this, this);

    int count = adapter.getCount();
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this_, "No Routes Points are available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();

        return;
    }

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);


    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String itemSearch = inputSearch.getText().toString();
            int itemLength = inputSearch.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {                  
                adapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(i);
                String listGet = adapter.getCursor().getString(RouteDB.I_NAME);
                if(itemLength<=listGet.length()){
                    if(listGet.contains(s)){
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

                    }
                }


            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });      

    db.close();
}
```

> **Adapter class**

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.lst_item.checkbox);
    chk.toggle();       
}

private class MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter
{
    OnClickListener btnOnClick;
    OnCheckedChangeListener chkOnChange;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, OnClickListener btnOnClick, OnCheckedChangeListener chkOnChange)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, c);
        this.btnOnClick = btnOnClick;
        this.chkOnChange = chkOnChange;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur)
    {
        String pointName = cur.getString(RouteDB.I_NAME);
        long pointID = cur.getLong(RouteDB.I_ID);
        String routeSpeed = cur.getString(RouteDB.I_SPEED);
        String routeType = cur.getString(RouteDB.I_TYPE);
        boolean visible = (cur.getInt(RouteDB.I_VISIBLE) == 1);


        view.setTag(pointID);

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.lst_item.checkbox);
        checkbox.setText(pointName);
        checkbox.setTag(pointID);
        checkbox.setChecked(visible);
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(chkOnChange);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.lst_item.btnMore);
        button.setTag(pointID);
        button.setOnClickListener(btnOnClick);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add listener for method `filter(s, listener)`, because called `filter(s)` will do nothing when the filter process finished so no UI update.

Comment: Can u explain a little more about this listener. What i figure out is that cursor may be needed to filtered and these filtered values should be stored in a new cursor.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you just need to set a `FilterQueryProvider` for your adapter or override `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` to filter data. I forgot that `ResourceCursorAdapter` will notify itself when filter process done.

Comment: @Minhtdh can u provide some source code for understanding the concept on these functions.

Comment: any help on this matter plz